# Plot over figimage

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot over an watermark using `figimage`, but no matter what I do, the image ends up on top of the plot.

Here is my code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

im = np.zeros((40,40,3), dtype=np.float)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.figimage(im, 100, 60)
plt.scatter([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], zorder=10)
plt.show()
```

result:
[image: result]

I've tried using the `zorder` argument, but that doesn't work either. Any idea how I can get an image behind the plot?

Comment: I'm not able to replicate the figure using your code. Mine plots all the points and there is no black square.

Comment: The second and third argument of `figimage` are coordinates in pixels. Try adjusting those to get the square on top of the scatter.

Comment: I think that the axis is being drawn over the figimage. You could try setting alpha=0.5 in the call to figimage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zorder` is indeed the way to go here. You will want the axes to have a higher zorder than the image. (This is because the `figimage` is a child of the figure, not the axes.)

So,

```
ax.set_zorder(1)
im.set_zorder(0)
```

puts the image behind the axes. Now that may be undesired, because it's hidden. So in addition you would then need to make the axes background transparent.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

im = np.zeros((40,40,3), dtype=np.float)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = fig.figimage(im, 100, 60)
ax.scatter([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

ax.set_zorder(1)
im.set_zorder(0)
ax.patch.set_visible(False)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Note that depending on the use case, you might want to use `OffsetImage` instead. See [the demo](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/demo_annotation_box.html) about it.